# Как найти на компьютере склонированный c git репозиторий?

Tags: git

Вечером скачал с git репозиторий, на утро не помню куда скачал. Как можно найти его?

Comment: поиск по `.git`

Comment: посмотреть в истории команд оболочки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В корневой папке рабочей копии `git` присутствует скрытая папка `.git`

Воспользуйтесь поиском. Как именно — зависит от используемой вами ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Выполните поиск по дискам на компьютере и укажите условие - показывать только файлы созданные вчера. "Как именно — зависит от используемой вами ОС." По ним и посмотрите, чего же вы вчера еще наделали ;-)